# How to create html element for each object in collection?

Tags: spring-boot

I have String like this:

```
{"response":{"count":997,"items":[{"id":2943,"first_name":"Vasya","last_name":"Babich","can_access_closed":true,"is_closed":false,"screen_name":"antanubis","track_code":"24fc13d6ZwhuhzyM9V1oRkohiruY-zXeoP1aliqA-1dA4qgxJrQAYSTQYe6kVWsTTKkXWWybQrHU"},{"id":231329886,"first_name":"Vasya","last_name":"Babich","can_access_closed":true,"is_closed":false,"screen_name":"lydka_lydka_lydka","track_code":"a348ab0aAo3CxaTAGsTDu4mpMdBMMjYxgAmOnr7PvUWgaanh141l5NGe_PlLz8a8unX1eOUxXj-GCo6esKk"}]}}
```

I want to show each value of "items" to user in browser and then user should be able to select one of them and save in database and in his own page in the website. I guess I should use loop and create html element for each item. But how to do this? What data type should I use to manipulate this data and store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html) is the most widely used view/template engine with Spring Boot and can handle your loop requirement. [Spring MVC](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-mvc-tutorial#:%7E:text=A%20Spring%20MVC%20is%20a%20Java%20framework%20which,spring%20framework%20like%20Inversion%20of%20Control%2C%20Dependency%20Injection.) enables you to manage your app behavior and define the data bound to HTML pages (views). You will need a database and there are lots of options. Check out [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) which makes it easy to work with all major database technologies.